# Exact repetitive method for AlarmManager

Tags: android

Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact.
For my app this is very bad news.

There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

But I do not see any 'setRepetitiveExact' method, what does this means ? they completely discourage this thing and they did not even made an API :S ?

I know it can drain battery but I still want to use it, I need to be exact!, I do not want this to happen eventually when the phone wakes up :S...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does this means ? they completely discourage this thing and they did not even made an API :S ?

Correct.

> I still want to use it, I need to be exact!

Then do it yourself. Use `setExact()` to set up the first event. In the handler for that event (e.g., `BroadcastReceiver`), set up the next event with another call to `setExact()`.

Comment: They still could leave public API for this. It was enough to discourage using. Now everyone that will want repetitive exact method will have to implement by their own :). But it is okey, I guess that is the point where everyone should ask them self if it is necessary to have that kind of thing in the code. Tnx